# What does it mean in C++ "It does not own the underlying data, and so is cheap to copy or assign"

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm reading about [mutable_buffer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/mutable_buffer.html) and it says

> The mutable_buffer class provides a safe representation of a buffer
>   that can be modified. It does not own the underlying data, and so is
>   cheap to copy or assign.

By copy I think it mean copying data using memcpy. What does **assign** mean?

Also if I have a pointer to a data, can't I simply make mutable_buffer point to this data instead of do mine? Of course, if the sizes of both are consistent.

Comment: Usually means holding a raw pointer

Comment: @AndyG what is a raw pointer?

Comment: I think it means that when you copy a `mutable_buffer` object the data pointed to will not be copied, so copying a `mutable object` is cheap. It is not necessary to copy the data  because when you destroy the object the data pointed to will not be deleted. (*That* is the definition of non-ownership.) (With the caveat that I have never heard of this particular type.)

Comment: *"What does assing mean?"* `mutable_buffer a(...), b(...); a = b;`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I thought it was talking about copy and assign of the pointer, thanks, now I understood, it's talking about itself. Anyways, can I make the pointer point do my data?

Comment: "Copy" here doesn't mean using memcpy, as that wouldn't be a cheap operation. It means that copying the class instance won't copy the underlying data, but only a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [more context](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html) you can see that the boost buffers are constructed **from existing data aggregates** like arrays, `std::array`s, `boost::array`s or `std::vector`s. *These* are the owners of  the data, meaning they are responsible for allocation and deletion.

The `mutable_buffer` class, by contrast, just points to the data provided by one of the mentioned containers, does not acquire it when it is created and and does not delete it when it is destroyed; this is what's meant with "it does not own the data".

Because it consists just of a pointer and an integral size and could not care less about the data it points to it is cheap to create, copy, assign and destroy. (But obviously care must be taken that the data pointed to is still valid — that's the difference to e.g. a `std::vector` which takes automagically care of that no matter when and how often often you copy, create and destroy it. The downside is that copying a vector copies all the data.)

Comment: Given a mutable_buffer, can I make its buffer point to another buffer instead of filling data in it which would be expensive?

Comment: That's what assignment would do, potentially from a temporary. Without having tried it, something like `int arr1[] = {1}, arr2[] = {2,3}; mutable_buffer x(arr1); /* let x point to something else: */ x = mutable_buffer(arr2); ` could work.

Comment: What if some function passed a reference to a mutable_buffer? It expects me to fill it with data. I thougth of, instead of filling it, by passing a new pointer to it. However, I cannot simply assign the mutable_buffer reference to a new one, can I?

Comment: A reference is just an alias, you can do anything to the object it references that you could do through any other name the object has. But careful: If you create a mutable_buffer that points to local data (e.g. an array with automatic storage duration which you defined in the function) the data will be invalid outside the functoin. You'll have to use global data or allocate dynamically.